# Rename connection string in .NET with EPiServer 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, episerver

I have this connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear />
  <add 
    name="EPiServerDB" .... />
</connectionStrings>
```

And was wondering if it is possible to rename it to something else other that `EPiServerDB`. Is it possible? We really need that on the current project as this name conflicts with another connection string which we hoped to use from an earlier project. The reason why is that we are integrating the old business layer into our new solution.

We are using EPiServer CMS 7, if that matters.

Comment: The connection to EPiServer must as far as I know always be called EPiServerDB. You can't have the EPiServer API connected to two databases at the same time, that doesn't make sense.

The "old business layer" could use some other connection string name perhaps?

Comment: @Andreas I did this: http://world.episerver.com/Modules/Forum/Pages/Thread.aspx?id=70799&epslanguage=en + renamed all references to the connection string and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do what this forum post says:

http://world.episerver.com/Modules/Forum/Pages/Thread.aspx?id=70799&epslanguage=en

Plus I had to rename all references to the connection string.

Comment: Mark this answer as "answer" aswell, to make sure it's properly visible that this answer solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio, you can go to Project properties -> Settings and rename connection string there.

[image]

Comment: My project didn't contain a settings file. It offered me to create one, but it was empty.